# Editing object created from bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I used a bezier curve to create an architectural moulding profile. Extruded the shape and used solidfy and made exactly what was intended. I would like to find a way to cut the shape with a knife at a 45 degree angle. Suggestions?

Thank you!!

Comment: How about the knife cut tool?

Comment: Get into a front or left/right or top, orthographic view, and use the knife tool with Z (to cut through) and C (to constrain the resulting line to a horizontal or vertical direction, or a 45 degree angle

Answer (score 2):

Use the knife tool with K and press C to constrain your cut at 45 degree (or straight or vertically) If you need to cut both side of your mesh hit Z. when you are done press enter.[image]

[image]